# Openssl X509_set_pubkey() Crash in Android NDK

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, openssl, android-ndk

I am trying to make the most basic x509 public key cert file possible on Android in C via the NDK.  I built libcrypto and libssl (although I am currently only using libcrypto stuff) with the stuff from https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android.

Since I was having some problems getting this to work I ended up getting it working in linux where I have a more pleasant debugging setup.  The code I have which is working on my linux box is as follows:

```
void x509(RSA *rsa_keys) {        

    EVP_PKEY *evp = EVP_PKEY_new();
    X509 *x509 = X509_new();

    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evp, rsa_keys);

    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509),0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), (long) 60*60*24*365);

    X509_set_pubkey(x509, evp);

    unsigned char *out = NULL;

    int length = i2d_X509(x509, &out);

    FILE *x509_file = fopen("cert.cer", "w");
    fwrite(out, 1, length, x509_file);
}
```

This code runs fine and writes out a file which is parsed fine by openssl with

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -text -in cert.cer
```

When I run the same code in the NDK on Android I get as far as the X509_set_pubkey(x509, evp) call (determined by printout debugging) without any openssl errors reported by ERR_get_error() and then get a signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPPER) with a big stack trace

the only thing that seems very useful from the stack trace is that the crash happened deep in libcrypto.so

```
08-17 01:40:41.261: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #00  pc 00041d1a  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.261: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #01  pc 000357c6  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.261: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #02  pc 000337ba  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.261: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #03  pc 000338c8  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #04  pc 000339e6  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #05  pc 00033f00  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #06  pc 00033b20  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #07  pc 00033f44  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #08  pc 00033f9c  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #09  pc 000770e6  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #10  pc 00076fec  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #11  pc 00036b68  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
08-17 01:40:41.268: INFO/DEBUG(10354):          #12  pc 0007ed1a  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
```

The only thing I can think of is that there is a problem with the Openssl I built but that seems somewhat unlikely, any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be you need to call OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms() before using the RSA functions.